# Error while building android kernel with LTO ld.gold /root/build/install/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib: can not read directory: Permission denied

Tags: android, github, clang, kernel, lto

I was trying to build android kernel 4.9 for my oneplus 6 from source. I have built a few kernels successfully through the instructions I got from internet.
Recently I came across this clang LTO stuff and wanted build it.
While running it I got this error and I did mot find any information regarding how to fix it.

```
2023-10-18T09:45:35.0430644Z   EXPORTS arch/arm64/lib/lib-ksyms.o
2023-10-18T09:45:35.1493180Z aarch64-linux-gnu-ld.gold: error: /root/build/install/aarch64-linux-gnu/lib: can not read directory: Permission denied
2023-10-18T09:45:35.1510959Z make[2]: *** [../scripts/Makefile.build:591: arch/arm64/lib/lib-ksyms.o] Error 1
2023-10-18T09:45:35.1514928Z make[1]: *** [/home/runner/work/lineage_caf_kernel_oneplus_sdm845/lineage_caf_kernel_oneplus_sdm845/Makefile:1162: arch/arm64/lib] Error 2
2023-10-18T09:45:35.1516189Z make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

link for full workflow run : https://github.com/EonXsin/lineage_caf_kernel_oneplus_sdm845/actions/runs/6558957788/job/17813575496
```

How to fix this issue?